# Merging multiple react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, package.json

I have two react application App1 and App2 and I want to merge them in a single project in way that -

1. They should use common package.json
2. They should use common node dependencies.
3. They should not affect each other configuration and code structure.

I am using default webpack configuration available in the create-react tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the question? Are you expecting a step-by-step tutorial? Not really clear what you are expecting here.

Comment: How can I manage multi module application in react?

Comment: This is either too broad especially without code or a request for an external tutorial or tool, neither of which are on-topic for SO.